# Papervision3D books to buy

Tags: papervision3d, pv3d

Can anyone suggest me a good papervision3D book to read? I know as3 pretty well but I'm just starting out with pv3d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know of any books currently in print, but Amazon shows a promising looking book from Wiley - [Professional Papervision 3D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470742666) coming out on October 19th.

Other than that, I've mainly used the resources on [pv3d.org](http://www.pv3d.org) and the [API docs](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have been enjoying "Papervision3D Essentials" by Tondeur and Winder.  It's available now (at the end of 2009) and one of the chapters (chapter 8, on loading a Collada model) can be downloaded free.

Professional Papervision 3D looks good, too -- many of the code samples are available on the author's blog -- but it is still in the publishing pipeline for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Professional Papervision3D was released recently. But there is also another interesting book in the making by Apress/Friends of ED. It's called "Experience Papervision3D". As far as I could find out the authors will be Seb Lee-Delisle and Carlos Ulloa, two of Papervision3Ds core team, which makes it probably worthwhile waiting for its release. Unfortunately there is no information when this book will be available. To my knowledge the earliest date will be April 2010. Right now the book cannot be found on the Apress Site as well as on the Friends of ED Site. Only [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223790) is listing it as "currently unavailable".